# getView of Child Fragment returns null

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I am creating and replacing a fragment inside another fragments onViewCreated

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //add searchFragment to this fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(searchFragment==null)
            searchFragment=new SearchFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.updateFragmentContainer, searchFragment).commit();

        if(searchFragment.getView()==null){
            Log.d("getView","of search view is null");//the control always reaches here
        }
        listView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        if(listView!=null)
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);//the control never reaches here
        else
            searchFragment.setUpdateItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);//this is a function in the saerchFragment class; there too the listview obtained by findViewbyId is null
    }
```

Now theres a listView in the searchFragment whose onItemClickListener i want to set in the parent fragment. I have tried a lot of ways as shown above but none of them work as the listView returned by findViewById is always null.

Also the searchFragment functionality works just fine when i remove all these null pointer exceptions caused due to the listView.
I have also tried overriding the getView of the searchFragment and returning a reference of the view which was infalted during onCreateView but it too returned null.

EDIT
SearchFragment class

```
import android.content.ContentProviderClient;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    int rollNo;
    Button searchButton=null;
    EditText rollNoEditText=null;
    ListView listView=null;
    public SearchFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rollNoEditText=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.rollNoEditText1);
        searchButton=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.searchbutton1);
        if(searchButton!=null)
            searchButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        else
            Log.d("Search Button", "null");
        listView=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    }
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(rollNoEditText.getText().length()>0){
                try{
                rollNo=Integer.parseInt(rollNoEditText.getText().toString());
                if(rollNo>0){
                    listView.setAdapter(
                            new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), // Context.
                                    R.layout.item_parent_student,
                                    getStudentCurosr(),
                                    new String[] { "name","rollno","class","marks" },
                                    // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those
                                    // columns.
                                    new int[] {R.id.nameTextView2,R.id.rollNoTextView2,R.id.classTextView2,R.id.marksTextView2 }
                            ));
                }
                    //displayStudentInfo(rollNo);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please type a valid integer value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    private Cursor getStudentCurosr() {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.students.provider.studentcontentprovider/student/"+rollNo);
          Log.d("RollNO passed",""+rollNo);
          ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient = getActivity().getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(uri );
          Cursor cur = null;
        try {
            cur = contentProviderClient.query(uri,null,null, null, null);
            return cur;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cur;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getView of Child Fragment returns null

Fragment transactions are asynchronous so your new `SearchFragment` which you'll use in that replace transaction will not have its view available yet(it will happen in the future after  the `onViewCreated()` method finishes). You could pass the listener instance to the newly created `SearchFragment` instance and store inside it in a private field(in that setter you could also check and see if the `ListView` is available at that moment, if it is then also set the listener passed in). Then in one of `SearchFragment`'s lifecycle methods(like `onViewCreated()`) check that `OnItemClickListener` field, if it's `null` then set it on the `ListView` widget.

However, something tells me you're approaching this the wrong way and you should let the `SearchFragment` set its own listener on the `ListView` and pass whatever events to the parent fragment through `getParentFragment()` method.

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` didn't work for me..i wanted to set it in the parent fragment as i am using the search fragment in numerous places and not all of them need the onItemClicklistener and and implementation varies in the places where i have used it.

Comment: @thunderbird Pass the `OnItemCLickListener` to the `searchFragment` instance through a setter method and store it in a private field. Then in one of the lifecycles of the `SearchFragment`(like `onViewCreated()`) see if that field is `null`, if it's not null then assign it to the `ListView`.

Comment: freaking awesome dude...it finally worked...but would be work everytime? i am setting the `onItemClickListener` immediately after creating the fragment object and storing it in a reference ..is the onViewCreated of the child is only called after the parent's one is over?

Comment: @thunderbird The child transaction will be done at a later point in time so the parent's `onViewCreated()` will run first. If you want an extra check, in that setter also check if the `listView` reference is null(if it's not null it means the view of the `SearchFragment` is available). If the reference it's not null then also set the `OnItemCLickListener` in the same setter.

Comment: please update your answer with the comment so i can accept it as the answer.